# gnuplot: one strange horizontal line generated

Tags: gnuplot

In the following gnuplot command:
`set xrange [ -6615.715200000001 : 79388.5824 ]`
`set yrange [ -1.2 : 4 ]`
`set autoscale x`
`set palette model RGB`
`unset colorbox`
`unset xtics`
`unset ytics`
`set object 14 rectangle from 9063.54 ,-1.0 to 19375.449 ,-0.5 fillcolor rgb "#FF9A00" fillstyle solid 0.8 noborder
plot -1 notitle`
the generated chart is as following:
[image]

The confusing point is why the horizontal line at the bottom is generated. I am using gnuplot version 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

Because you plot it!

```
plot -1 notitle
```

plots a horizontal line at y=-1, which is inside your selected yrange.

If you want to show only the rectangle, use

```
plot 1/0 notitle
```